# Install performance schema helper in mysql workbench for mac

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to view the Performance Reports in MySQL Workbench. It shows a message "The Performance Schema helper schema (sys) is not installed ... ", and a button "Install Helper"
[image]

I am simply supposed to click the "Install Helper" button and it should install the helper already bundled in workbench package. But when I click the button, it asks me to select the location of mysql_upgrade tool.

[image]

The issue is I can't find the mysql_upgrade tool (dmg file or zip file)to download. Looks like a trivial issue but I have been struggling for the last few hours now.

workbench version: mysql-workbench-community-8.0.34-macos-arm64

OS Version: macOS Ventura. Version: 13.4.1